ROS2 Jazzy, How to change publisher nodes from a package
I have just followed the steps in https://docs.ros.org/en/jazzy/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Writing-A-Simple-Py-Publisher-And-Subscriber.html, and I would like to change the .py script so that the message published by the talker is "Changing the script: i".
I have changed it in the .py, but as the package is previously built it doesn't have any effect. How can it be done? In other words, I'd like to debug or run the nodes befores creating the package. How can I do it?

You have to re-build the package each time you make an edit to one of the files for it to take effect. There is no real way to "debug" the nodes you are writing besides building them within ros2.
Running colcon build in your ros2_ws will do this, and should be a step you take after any edit to your custom nodes while developing.
